# How to order the dependencies so that maven project can be built using multiple threads?

Tags: maven

I am trying to organize dependencies for my project so that I can build it with multiple threads. Currently build is taking a while because of unorganized dependencies.

Comment: Are you talking about multi-module projects and the order of the modules?

Comment: Yes, For a multi module project .